# How to send this type of body in post request in angular

Tags: angular

{
"name": "kiran",
"email": "sai123@gmail.com",
"phone_number": "123456789",
"type": "individual",
"billing": {
"address":{
"line1":"1234 Main Street",
"city":"San Francisco",
"state":"CA",
"postal_code":"94111",
"country": "US"
}
}
}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would help if you demonstrate what you have tried so far and / or tell us what libraries you want to use in order to do the request. Apart from that, checking the documentation of axios or fetch will help you get into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make an object of json.

like

```
var obj =   { "name": "kiran", "email": "sai123@gmail.com", "phone_number": "123456789", "type": "individual", "billing": { "address":{ "line1":"1234 Main Street", "city":"San Francisco", "state":"CA", "postal_code":"94111", "country": "US" } } }
```

Then

```
Post(obj:any)  {
          return this.http.post('apiUrlhere',{obj});
          }
```

and call it using

```
 this.Post(ObjHere)
 .subscribe(
  data => { 
   //result inside data
   });
```

Where [http](https://angular.io/guide/http) is

> private http: HttpClient